# insert function with user prompt

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to make an Oracle function to be used with Oracle SQL Developer that the user can type `cnp` from the keyboard and if the `cnp` size is = 13 then insert it into the table that the user has loaded. if it is not = 13 then a message appears.

I did the job but it shows me errors .. I tried, I documented but I did not find where I'm wrong.

here is my table, for now I just want `cnp` to add it, after I will introduce the rest of the attributes in the table.:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENT (

  CODCLIENT NUMBER,
  NUMECLIENT VARCHAR2(10),
  PRENUMECLIENT VARCHAR2(15),
  CNPCLIENT VARCHAR2(13),
  SERIECLIENT VARCHAR2(2),
  NUMARID VARCHAR2(6),
  SEX VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT NN_SEXC NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CK_SEXC CHECK((SEX) IN('MASCULIN','FEMININ')),
  ADRESA VARCHAR2(100),
  EMAIL VARCHAR2(50),
  TELEFON VARCHAR2(13),
  CONSTRAINT PK_CODCLIENT PRIMARY KEY (CODCLIENT)
);
```

And here is the error displayed:

```
old:DECLARE
    CNP varchar2(13);

BEGIN
    CNP := '&X' ;

    IF CNP.LENGTH = 13 THEN
        INSERT INTO CLIENT(CNPCLIENT) VALUES(CNP);
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CNP INCORECT');
    END IF;

END;
new:DECLARE
    CNP varchar2(13);

BEGIN
    CNP := '23241415151' ;

    IF CNP.LENGTH = 13 THEN
        INSERT INTO CLIENT(CNPCLIENT) VALUES(CNP);
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CNP INCORECT');
    END IF;

END;

Error starting at line : 30 in command -
DECLARE
    CNP varchar2(13);

BEGIN
    CNP := '&X' ;

    IF CNP.LENGTH = 13 THEN
        INSERT INTO CLIENT(CNPCLIENT) VALUES(CNP);
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CNP INCORECT');
    END IF;

END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 7, column 12:
PLS-00487: Invalid reference to variable 'CNP'
ORA-06550: line 7, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: Should be LENGTH(CNP) = 13

Comment: Thank you, it works. But now after it is executed the record says it is null. '1234567891235' this have 13 length.

Comment: It says `CNP` is null - or the insert errors because `SEX` is null (`NN_SEXC` says it can't be), or because `CODCLIENT` is null (that's the PK, so can't be null)? Your insert it only supplying a single column, and it has to do more than that.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I needed to put the column sex and the column codclient, i declared them and i put in the insert statement. Thank you for helping me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle `LENGTH` function has the following syntax:

> LENGTH( string1 )

You can find more about it here: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/length.php

In your code, instead of `IF CNP.LENGTH = 13` you should'e written the following:

```
IF LENGTH(CNP) = 13
```

I hope I helped!